# Blazor Server (NET 7): Uncaught (in promise) Error: Server returned an error on close: Connection closed with an error

Tags: blazor-server-side, .net-7.0, circuit

I get this error when starting up my Blazor Server application and looking in the Browser's Dev tools; Console tab. What I see is that the browser goes immediately into "reconnect" mode.

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Server returned an error on close: Connection closed with an error.
at Ft._processIncomingData (blazor.server.js:1:73086)
at Ft.connection.onreceive (blazor.server.js:1:67009)
at i.onmessage (blazor.server.js:1:51322)
```

Then, on a 20 second interval I get this entry:

```
Error: Error: Circuit host not initialized.
```

My startup logs show no issues except my identity cookie is expired.

```
Cookies was not authenticated. Failure message: Ticket expired
```

I did attempt to trap/debug the CircuitHandler object.  On putting a breakpoint in the OnCircuitOpenedAsync event I didn't trap any errors but I also received no event activity.  This seemed odd to me but its new to me so I'm not sure if I did it right.

```
    public class CircuitHandlerService : CircuitHandler
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Singleton
    /// </summary>
    private readonly ICircuitUserService circuitUserService;

    public string CircuitId { get; private set; }

    public CircuitHandlerService(
        ICircuitUserService circuitUserService)
    {
        this.circuitUserService = circuitUserService;
    }

    public override Task OnCircuitOpenedAsync(Circuit circuit, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        CircuitId = circuit.Id;
        return base.OnCircuitOpenedAsync(circuit, cancellationToken);
    }

    public override Task OnCircuitClosedAsync(Circuit circuit, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        circuitUserService.Disconnect(circuit.Id);
        return base.OnCircuitClosedAsync(circuit, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```